# IONIC não gera projeto e não da erro

Tags: ionic4

Eu preciso muito da ajuda de alguém pois estou a 3 dias com o mesmo problema, mas sem alguma solução. Ao executar o seguinte comando fica apenas parado e não continua o processo de criação do projeto ... 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas e apenas na criação do projeto pois o Ionic serve continua a funcionar com outro projeto criado que tenho.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

[Baixar a correção do node.js e instale](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Use os comandos
**Passo 1**

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm install -g ionic
```

**passo 2**

```
cd c:\
ionic start projeto01 blank
```

Comment: Cara muito Obrigado pela ajuda , mas ainda sim não funcionou , eu ja desinstalei totalmente o ionic , limpando cachê do npm e tudo , já atualizei a versão do npm tbm mas ainda assim sem resultado

Comment: continua o mesmo erro?

Comment: Sim ainda continuo com o mesmo erro.

Comment: Use npm uninstall -g ionic e repita o processo

Comment: Ainda Continuo com o mesmo problema

Comment: O erro deveria ter mudado, coloca a foto?